# Rewrite SQL Server Stored Procedure to MySQL(MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures, mariadb

I need to rewrite stored procedure from MS SQL Server syntax to MySQL of MariaDB standart. I've been struggling with this for hours. I'd never imagine there are so many differences. Is there any tool that can do it automatically? Here is the stored procedure's code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Validate @username nvarchar(50), @email nvarchar(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM Users WHERE Username = @username

IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmp) < 1)
    BEGIN               
        INSERT INTO Users(Username, Email, FirstLaunch) VALUES (@username, @email, GETDATE())
        SELECT 1
    END
ELSE IF(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), (SELECT FirstLaunch FROM #tmp)) > 8)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Users SET Email = @email WHERE Username = @username
        SELECT 0
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Users SET Email = @email WHERE Username = @username
        SELECT 1
    END

IF OBJECT_ID('#tmp') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP TABLE #tmp
END
```

It check if the user is present within Users table and if he initially logged in more than 7 days ago.

Comment: The stored-code languages for different makes of database server are vastly different from each other, as you have discovered. Your best bet for porting stored procedures is to implement them from scratch using the same specifications. This is a way the vendors get their customers locked in to their products.

Comment: Have you even tried something???  Post your code.  Have you read MySQL documentation on how to create sp???

Comment: @Eric Sir, you've missed the sentense "I've been struggling with this for hours". It meant to say, that while I tried to rewrite it from scratch, as O. Jones suggested, I couldn't manage to get even first 5 lines compiled without error. I don't know how posting those 5 lines of incorrect MySQL would improve this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementations of stored procedure languages differ from each other. MS SQL Server's language (Transact-SQL) was originally developed by Sybase. MySQL's dialect is bit different. Not really a customer lock-in, just that things have evolved over time.

To implement the procedure in MySQL, you can use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Validate( 
in_username varchar(50), 
in_email varchar(100)
)
begin

declare v_cnt int;
declare v_first_launch datetime;

select 1, FirstLaunch into v_cnt, v_first_launch
from Users
where Username = in_username;

if (v_cnt = 1) then
  update Users
  set Email = in_email 
  where Username = in_username;

  if (datediff(now(), v_first_launch) > 8) then
    select 0;
  else
    select 1;
  end if;
else
  insert into Users(Username, Email, FirstLaunch) 
  values (in_username, in_email, now());

  select 1;
end if;

end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will accept it as correct although I'm not sure how zeroes and ones are returned in your implementations. Documentation says that in MySQL SPs don't have return values. I had to use output parameters instead.

Comment: Functions have return values. Stored procedures return result sets (rows+columns) or values through output variables. Your MS SQL Server procedure returns result sets (single 0  or 1). The provided MySQL procedure works alike, no need to use output variables.

Comment: (Bug: check how `v_first_launch` is being set.)

Comment: If it weren't for the 0/1 return based on 8 days, the entire procedure boils down to a single `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..` statement.

Comment: @RickJames, v_first_launch is set correctly. It gets value only when user is found and it is only used then. The second comment is correct, just that the question was about the procedure syntax, not the logic.

Comment: @slaakso - I think you need `first_launch INTO v_first_launch`

Comment: @RickJames, the code does exactly that "select 1, FirstLaunch into v_cnt, v_first_launch..."